# OWASP ZAP Java application will not load on OS X

Tags: macos, java

I am running OS X 10.7.5 and just applied the Java 7 JDK update to get my Java version up to 1.7.0_21 and the ZAP application will not load.

I did a restart after Java 7 installation and still no joy. I downloaded the application [from Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/downloads/detail?name=OWASP_ZAP_2.1.0_OSX.zip&can=2&q=).

My system log shows a series of errors as follows upon attempting to launch the application:

```
4/27/13 12:46:31.104 PM [0x0-0x69069].org.zaproxy.zap.ZAP: Error: could not find libjava.dylib
4/27/13 12:46:31.104 PM [0x0-0x69069].org.zaproxy.zap.ZAP: Failed to GetJREPath()
4/27/13 12:46:31.105 PM JavaAppLauncher: failed to JNI_CreateJavaVM (-1): CFBundle 0x100302db0 </Applications/OWASP ZAP.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre1.7.0_21.jre> (framework, loaded): (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86003f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ea17d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86003d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86003d14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   JavaAppLauncher                     0x000000010000326f JavaAppLauncher + 12911
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cf3972a -[NSThread main] + 68
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cf396a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8dcad8bf _pthread_start + 335
    8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8dcb0b75 thread_start + 13
)
```

I have searched my system for 'libjava.dylib' without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through the terminal:

```
/Applications/OWASP\ ZAP.app/Contents/Java/zap.sh
```

Looks like it has some issues locating the Java runtime when loading it through launchpad